# Wordpress crop image not working

Tags: css, cropping

I have the following CSS:

```
.crop {
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

to crop an image when the screen shrinks. It works in a normal HTML file, but in Wordpress, the result is a compressed image, not a cropped one. How can I fix this?

Comment: WordPress does not alter how CSS works. That part is rendered in the browser after the page leaves the server. There must be conflicting rules somewhere, but it is a pure CSS problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible your theme is setting

```
width: auto;
```

on the image, possibly as part of some responsive tweaking. This would cause it to keep its normal proportion but with the specified height.

Can you provide a URL to look at?

Comment: umm... I will put off coming soon mode until you reply.

Comment: Link is provectium.com/support

Comment: Never mind - I see the image now. Hang on.

Comment: SO if you set `max-width: 850px` on the image, it will stop the shrinking. Then if you set `overflow: hidden` on the parent div, it will hide the rest of the image. You could then add some border-radius to make the right side look rounded too. Good luck!

Comment: Ok. Let me try it..